# aws lambda function to use host file

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I'm using AWS Lambda functions, in node.js.
is there any way to configure the lambda function to use hosts records?

for example:

```
{domain:'www.example.com',ip:'190.10.20.30'}
```

Comment: do you want to redirect particular domain request to some other server?

Comment: i want to override the dns lookup of the http module with a given ip, to pass a CDN and get content from the origin server

Comment: @LiorGoldemberg Did you ever find a solution or workaround for this? I am dealing with the same issue

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer i have used docker for that eventually

Comment: @LiorGoldemberg Thanks for the update! Shame their is no way to update the host file for a lambda

Comment: A much cleaner solution would be to use Route53 private DNS for your VPC.

Comment: I stumbled upon the same issue, but in my case I was using Playwright framework to make http requests. My solution was to use chromium's own dns override option, and pass an argument with the following format: 

`args: ['--host-resovler-rules=MAP example.com 127.0.0.1']`